# How to order the elements of a mutableList in kotlin in a custom way

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a list of objects in kotlin, but I need the order to be defined by the user, that it can be ordered in any way chosen by the user, but I don't know how to achieve it.

How can I do it?

Comment: You will need to be more specific if you want an answer.

Comment: Use ``sortBy``/``sortedBy`` and pass in the sorting function you want to use, or ``sortedWith`` and pass in a ``Comparator``. You can make a bunch of predefined functions / comparators that the user can select from, and pass one in. If you need them to be able to configure things, you'll need to come up with a way to produce a function/comparator that handles whatever parameters and logic you want the user to be able to provide, and obviously that's trickier than just having a predefined ``orderByName`` function they can pick

Comment: What kind of order do we want to achieve here? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: Hello, I would like the order to be defined by the user, to take each element and place it in the position they want, for example if they have a list of colors that order them the way they want, it could be first blue, second red and third green , or first green, second blue and last red, which can be ordered in all possible ways defined by the user or the person who handles that interacts with the application